# MFC: How to determine the currently HIGHLIGHTED item in a CComboBox list (NOT selected item)

Tags: mfc

This is similar BUT NOT THE SAME as C# questions, but as everyone knows, MFC is not .NET.  MFC objects do NOT have the same runtime properties as .NET objects.

Comment: I don't think you can highlight an item without selecting it. You can cancel the selection, but it *is* a selection.

Comment: In a combo box, click on the dropdown, then move your mouse over the items in the list.  The items are highlighted to show if you hit the enter key, that would be the item that would be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Owner Draw mechanism (even though it's a simple text list), the callback has flags/attributes that shows which entry needs to be "highlighted", which we post a notification as to which item is currently "highlighted".

The complexity was MUCH less than trying to implement basic ComboBox functionality in a ComboBoxEx control (e.g. basic ComboBox styles do NOT apply to ComboBoxEx - don't ask).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be of much help but....every time the highlighted item changes you receive a CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO message.

I don't thik the information you receive with this message is going to help but if you really need to know the highlighted item maybe you could calculate it based on the mouse position and the height of every item. A bit tricky but possible.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think this may give us what we want.  We started looking at CComboBoxEx that has some "additional" notifications, one includes the structure you mentioned, which has a flag that tells is whether the item is "selected".  I'll let you know!

Comment: ComboBoxEx was much too difficult to implement just the basic, simple ComboBox functionality, let alone implement my need.  Ended up using the Owner Draw mechanism - see my answer for more.